# getline(isstream, string) in C++

Tags: c++, getline

I'm working on learning C++, and still keep running into stupid problems as I am yet unfamiliar with C++ libraries, and common errors, etc.

right now, the following piece of my code fails:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

void getInt(int & val){
    string output;
    getline(cin output.c_str());
    val = atoi(output.c_str());
}
```

and gives me this error when I try to compile it:

```
test.cpp: In function void getInt(int&):
test.cpp:51: error: expected ) before output
test.cpp:51: error: no matching function for call to getline(std::istream&)
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: `getline(cin output.c_str());` lacks a comma.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Wow - easy fix. I hate working with emacs in the terminal lol. Can you post an answer so I can accept it? You were the first to it. =P

Comment: Really? This is your question? You didn't do any debugging?

Comment: Missed the opportunity. At this point, adding another answer would just be noise.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did debug - I just missed the obvious. I am working in an environment AND a language I am unfamiliar with. I simply misunderstood the error - I thought it was somehow grabbing the wrong "getline" function from some other location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getline` takes two arguments. When passing multiple arguments to a function, you must separate them with a comma. In addition, the second argument can be a `std::string`, so just pass `output` directly:

```
getline(cin, output);
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
getline(cin, output); // comma, no .c_str()
```

If you do `.c_str()`, you're going to invoke undefined behavior when you try to read data into an *empty*, *read only* area of memory. That's some bad mojo. Of course, as Lightness points out in the comments, it won't even compile because `c_str()` is a `const char*` and `getline()` needs a `char*` (non-`const`) (but even if you did manage to get it to compile, it's important to understand the undefined behavior).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I don't need .c_str(). I didn't have it originally, but I added it when I started trying to fix the problem.

Comment: It's not "don't need .c_str()" -- it's "_can't_ use .c_str()".

Comment: Actually, it'll result in a compilation error, since `std::string::c_str()` results in a `char const*`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, certainly, I wasn't trying to imply it would correctly compile. I added that last comment in case he tries to cast away the const-ness to get it to compile.

Comment: @Cornstalks: You said "you're going to invoke undefined behavio[u]r", which is impossible in a non-compilable program. But okay.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There, added a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
getline(cin output.c_str());
```

You forgot a comma, skippy.

Also, your second argument is wrong! The string itself is just called `output`, and you should only apply `.c_str()` to it when you need to obtain a C-style character buffer for use with C APIs. i.e. not here.

```
getline(cin, output);
```

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. He is correct that that was my problem, and I don't think he was meaning to be disrespectful with the "skippy" or anything? +1

Comment: Thank you, @Jonathan. No, "skippy" is an affectionate pet name for only my favourite OPs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Highly suspicious... are you suuuure it's your favourite?

Comment: @ThePhD As is your username, but you don't see me whining about it! :P

Comment: @ThePhD Just barely got your username reference, btw. LOVE that show. =)